How do I generate @ApiResponse and @Operation annotations in the API code
I have this config for the maven plugin:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>query</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                <generatorName>jaxrs-spec</generatorName>
                <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                <output>${generated.source.directory}</output>
                <configurationFile>${specification.source.directory}/query-config.json</configurationFile>
                <inputSpec>${specification.source.directory}/query.yaml</inputSpec>
                <configOptions>
                    <library>openliberty</library>
                    <serializationLibrary>jsonb</serializationLibrary>
                    <sourceFolder>/</sourceFolder>
                    <useJakartaEe>false</useJakartaEe>
                    <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                    <useMicroProfileOpenAPIAnnotations>true</useMicroProfileOpenAPIAnnotations>
                    <useSwaggerAnnotations>false</useSwaggerAnnotations>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

The config file specifies packages for model and for api.
The OpenApi spec look like this:
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Generated API
  version: "1.0"
servers:
- url: http://view-localhost:80/
- url: https://view-localhost:443/
tags:
- name: Query
  description: Example for Stackoverflow question
paths:
  /query/v1/{identity}:
    get:
      tags:
      - Query
      summary: Example for Stackoverflow question
      description: Illustrate structure of real specification
      operationId: answerQuery
      parameters:
      - name: identity
        in: path
        description: reference number
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Example that should have an @ApiResponse annotation in the generated code
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                required:
                - info
                type: object
                properties:
                  info:
                    type: string
                    nullable: false
        "400":
          description: "Bad Request, supplied parameters are invalid"
        "401":
          description: "Unauthorized, caller is not authorized to call this service"

The generated code contains a method named answerQuery, like expected but there is no @ApiResponse or @Operation annotations on that method.
There is only a javadoc comment that lists three @return values, each having the description from the different response codes in the specification.
Is there any configuration for the maven plugin that adds these annotations (from the microprofile library instead of swagger)?
